# Is Thylakoid membrane continuous with the Inner membrane of Choloroplast?

Tags: cell-biology, chloroplasts

This [article](https://byjus.com/neet/what-is-the-function-of-thylakoid/#:%7E:text=The%20inner%20membrane%20of%20chloroplast%20is%20sometimes%20continuous,characteristics%20with%20the%20prokaryotic%20membranes%20such%20as%20cyanobacteria.) mentions that thylakoid membrane is  continuous with the inner membrane of cholorplast

> Thylakoid membrane encloses the innermost compartment or thylakoid
> lumen. The inner membrane of chloroplast is sometimes continuous with
> the thylakoid membrane. Thylakoid membrane is composed of
> phospholipids and galactolipids. It is similar to the inner membrane
> of chloroplast and also shares some characteristics with the
> prokaryotic membranes such as cyanobacteria

but a [answer](https://biology.stackexchange.com/a/23972/65724) on stack exchange on mentions that they are closed at the end

> . Each , of these lamellae is composed of double membranes joined at
> the ends & each membrane is 100-200 angstrom thick....

Accordind to me thylakoid membrane should be continuous with inner membrane because it has originated from the same membrane, but i am not sure about it??

Comment: key word, "sometimes" also what makes you think they originated from the same membrane, chloroplasts were likely one free living bacteria.

Answer (score 0):

There is a third membrane (thylakoid membrane) enclosed inside the chloroplast, not any more membranes. This is independent of the double chloroplast membrane. It folds to form the thylakoids, enclosing the (continuous) thylacoid lumen.

> Chloroplasts are surrounded by a double membrane similar to the double membrane found within a mitochondrion. Within the chloroplast is **a third membrane** that forms stacked, disc-shaped structures called thylakoids. Embedded in the **thylakoid membrane** are molecules of chlorophyll, a pigment [...] The thylakoid membrane encloses an internal space called the thylakoid lumen or space. Other types of pigments are also involved in photosynthesis, but chlorophyll is by far the most important.

[image]

Image (CC) and information source: [OpenStax, Concepts of Biology](https://bio.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Introductory_and_General_Biology/Book%3A_Principles_of_Biology/01%3A_Chapter_1/10%3A_Photosynthesis/10.02%3A_The_structure_of_the_chloroplast)